# Search column in one sheet for cells containing string, then reference them another sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

What I'd like to do is search for a specific string in a column in one sheet (let's call it Sheet 1), and reference the values in a column *adjacent* to those matched cells in another sheet (Sheet 2).

To make it more clear, here's a diagram illustrating what I'm trying to do:

[image]

What I'd like to do is search the Customer column in Sheet 1 for "Acme", then populate a column in Sheet 2 with each Acme entry's corresponding sample, ignoring any non-Acme entries.

I'm going to guess that this would be more complex than a regular Excel macro and would require a VBA function. Either way, I would be immensely grateful if someone could at least point me in the right direction as to where to begin searching.

Comment: Excel formula is enough to achieve this. Would you prefer to do it by `VBA` or regular excel formulas?

Comment: No attempt at a formula nor even row and column headings in the image of sample data.

Comment: @harun24hr I appreciate the follow-up. There would be no difference to me, but I think VBA might be better so there is less of a chance of the formula being accidentally fudged by other users.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a single sheet example, without VBA, that you can adapt to your needs:

In **D1** enter:

Acme

In **D2** enter the **array formula**:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$B$9,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$9=$D$1,ROW($A$1:$A$9)),ROW(1:1)),2),"")
```

and copy down.

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This will find the first row of sheet1 with customer "Acme".  It will find the first row of sheet2 with the customer name "Acme" and add the contents of sheet1 "Acme" row column C to whatever is in sheet2 Acme row column "C".  It assumes these numbers are values, not strings.  You can change that by deleting the addition.  You can also change columns or anything else to suit your needs.

```
Sub updateSheet2()
Dim customerNameColumnSheet1 As String, customerNameColumnSheet2 As String    
Dim lastRowSheet1 As Long
Dim lastRowSheet2 As Long
Dim customerName As String
Dim Sheet1Row As Long
Dim Sheet2Row As Long

customerNameColumnSheet1 = "A"
customerNameColumnSheet2 = "A"
customerName = "Acme" ' or customerName = Sheet1.Range("A12").value, etc

lastRowSheet1 = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, customerNameColumnSheet1).End(xlUp).row
lastRowSheet2 = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, customerNameColumnSheet2).End(xlUp).row

With Sheet1.Range(customerNameColumnSheet1 & "1:" & customerNameColumnSheet1 & lastRowSheet1)
    Set c = .Find(customerName, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        Sheet1Row = c.row
        With Sheet2.Range(customerNameColumnSheet2 & "1:" & customerNameColumnSheet2 & lastRowSheet2)
            Set D = .Find(customerName, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)
            If Not D Is Nothing Then
                Sheet2Row = D.row
                Sheet2.Range("C" & Sheet2Row).Value = Sheet1.Range("C" & Sheet1Row).Value' + Sheet2.Range("C" & Sheet2Row).Value  ' assuming values, not string
            End If
        End With
    End If
End With

End Sub
```